# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable when importing glob in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, import, glob

I am working with Eclipse Kepler(2013) and python 3.3.2 and running a simple import like

```
import glob
a = glob.glob('*')
print(a)
```

gives a:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is not the case if I run the same code in Idle. I know I am missing something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does `glob.__file__` returns?

Comment: **Never** use the same name of a built-in module or function.

Comment: It is mentioned in one answer below, but the solution is very simple: use `import glob as glob`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably in your Eclipse environment there's a module named `glob` that gets imported before the standard library one.

Try printing the `glob.__file__` to check it out.

Comment: THis comment helped understanding the problem. Grazie Paolo!

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me was i changed `import glob` to `from glob import glob`  at the top of the file.

Comment: This is the best answer here

Answer (score 8):

In some cases people end up using same file name as built in modules. **Don't name your file as "glob.py".**

Comment: Thanks! that was it.  Also, if you have a left-over `glob.pyc` file that got created from your `glob.py` - clean it too...

Answer (score 4):

This is only possible if you've defined a package named `glob` in the module search path, so instead of loading the built-in module `glob` python is importing that package.

Something like this in the module search path

```
glob
├── glob.py
├── glob.pyc
├── __init__.py
└── __init__.pyc
```

will produce the same error:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.__file__
'/home/monty/py/glob/__init__.pyc'
>>> glob.glob()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

You need to change the name of this package to something else because it seems to be present on the module search path used by eclipse.

Comment: LOL. I named my python script 'glob.py' and wondered why I couldn't access the glob module.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `import glob` to `from glob import glob`. It works fine for me. You can try it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).